# how to Embed video into tkinter window in raspberry pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I want to make Queue Management application using Raspberry pi. I want to design my window using tkinter. On that window I want some portion will show the token no and counter no and other portion will show videos. How could i embed video on my window. Other functions I could manage easily but no idea about video. Please help me how could i embed video in my window.

Comment: Perhaps you should use a `WebBrowser` Control instead then.

Comment: I've had a look at the link in your question. It isn't a live stream link, its just a link to a web page. This wont play in axwindowsmedia player. As @Jaxi said, you could try the webbrowser control, but I've just tried it with the property `.ScriptErrorsSupress` set to true (the site wont work with it set to false - too many errors). I get duplicated audio. So the built in webbrowser control is no good. You'll have to see if there's another browser  control available.